# Is there a a storage limit per node in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am hoping to create a Cassandra cluster, and wondering what is the maximum size i should allocate for a given Cassandra data node. I read an article sometime back saying maximum size should be 2TB. I need to confirm. How will this affect performance ect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the cassandra-stress tool to get a very very crude idea of what your hardware will be able to do, but it sounds like you're not even at that point.

About the only rule of thumb I can give you at this point is that you're much more likely to be iops bound than disk space bound.  (Corollary: deploy on SSDs.)